# Meteor js insertion into mongodb collection using variable fetched by running python script

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, meteor, amazon-s3

This code gets the data required from the python code, which in turn fetches the list of objects from aws s3. it gets the code using stdout. I've managed to break the string i fetch from python, tokenize it and put it in an javascript array. The issue lies when i try to put it in the collection using the code below. It shows garbage values have been put into the collection.

here is the python code

```
import sys
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_KEY = '##################' 
AWS_SECRET = '*********************************' 
REGION_HOST = 's3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com' 
aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET, host=REGION_HOST)#, 
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('####3')
z = 0
stp = ""
for file_key in bucket.list():
    p = file_key.name
    y = p.split("-")    
    for a in y:
        z = z + 1
        if(z % 2 == 0):
             stp = stp + a + " "
        z = 0

print(stp)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Here is the java script code.
The python code is called by the javascript 
i get back the string in javascript by stdout.
I split the string store it in a variable in javascript.
Problem is that i dont know how exactly i am supposed to insert in my collection.

```
Garbage = new Mongo.Collection("garbag");
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var exec = Npm.require('child_process').exec;
    var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var out;
    var arr;
    var a =  3
    Meteor.methods({
        callPython: function() {
            var fut = new Future();
            exec('python /home/piyush/pycloud/v1.py', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                if (error) {
                    throw new Meteor.Error(error, error);
                }
                if (stdout) {
                    console.log(stdout);
                    out = stdout;
                    arr = out.split(" ");
                    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                        console.log(arr[i]);
                    }                       
                }
                if (stderr) {
                    console.log("mital");
                }
                new Fiber(function() {
                    fut.return('Python was here');
                }).run();

            });
            console.log("miitttaall");
            console.log(arr);
            if(a < 5){                               
                var crr = [{area: "pashan"  , amount : arr[0]},
                        {area: "balewadi", amount : arr[1]}, 
                        {area: "aundh"   , amount : arr[2]}];
                _.each(crr , function(doc){
                    Garbage.insert(doc);
                });     
                console.log("willthisprint");
            }   
            return arr;
        },

    });
}
```

Comment: can you share what `stdout` is, and what is inserted in the collection?

Comment: stdout is a string of numbers like "2 3 4 5", that string is tokenized into array elements and i intend to put those array elements as my value for inserting into collection. Sample collection insert value is  var crr = {area: "xyz", amount : arr[0]} where arr[0] is the 1st element that should have been tokenized from the string @Guig